# Is it possible to embed a video uploaded to Facebook in an app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube-javascript-api, android-youtube-api

There are 2 types of videos on Facebook - (A) those that are links to videos (assume YouTube only) and (B) those that are uploaded directly to Facebook.

My question is two-fold. Provided the user uses Facebook connect,

1. Is it possible for me to extract the ID of the YouTube video (Type "A") from the Graph API? I guess I can then use Youtube api to embed those videos in my app using Youtube helper etc.
2. Is it possible for me to embed the videos uploaded to Facebook directly (Type "B") into my app? If so, how?

Cheers

Comment: Did you fins a solution for point 2?

Comment: Sadly, I have not had any luck so far.